# Unable to locate package spice-vdagent in debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, spice

I am running a live debian as a guest OS in VMM.

```
$ sudo apt install spice-vdagent
...
E: unable to locate package spice-vdagent
```

Do I need to add some repository first?

The repository configuration contains:

```
user@debian:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/base.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the live images, there are no repository indexes in the base image, so you need to update first:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install spice-vdagent
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain somehow what apt needs to find a package? How are repo indexes used, and when are they created?

Comment: See [the relevant chapter in the Debian reference manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_package_management_internals).